# What is the best practice to store time-related events in neo4j

Tags: database, database-design, neo4j

I am trying to create a contact network on a neo4j graph database instance. When I am fumbling around with the relationships between Lecturers and Lectures, I need to store the time schedules of each lecture session.

My previous idea was to embed such info as attributes of relations. However, it made the graph look messy and **took forever to create all relations**. I wonder what is the best practice to store the event/transaction-like data in a graph database?

I will frequently retrieve the lectures that the teachers teach at each time slot. This means I need to retrieve the entire course schedule of a given faculty at a given academic week and day.

Here is a snapshot of a subplot containing courses and teachers.

[image: visualisation of a subplot]

The green nodes are lectures. And the yellow ones denote lecturers. The relationships are named 'TEACHES' and each of them has a few specific attributes, including:

```
<id>: 1331
building: Humanities Building
period: 6
room: 806
week: 12
weekday: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info about your specific use case to determine the proper data model, so here are some general ideas.

A `Course` should contain *course-specific* properties that rarely need to change across sections and lecturers (maybe `building`, `room`, etc.).

Ideally, you should only need a single `TEACHES` relationship between a lecturer and a course (or section). You would need to arrange the properties to make that possible. For example, some of its properties could be lists instead of scalars.

If a `Course` can have multiple sections and lecturers, then you could introduce `Section` nodes containing section-specific properties (some properties, like `weekday`, probably should be lists instead of scalars).